# How can I store rdf data in a browser that is queryable using SPARQL?

Tags: angularjs, browser, local-storage, rdf, sparql

I'm building an AngularJS application and I want to store rdf data locally in the browser which I can query with SPARQL, without having to be online. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: duplicate (with more detail) on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/29506/what-sparql-queryable-browser-storage-solutions-exist-for-rdf-data .

Answer (score 2):

You could store the facts in a local storage and build a query engine to query it - for example by building on top of an [existing SQL engine](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js).

Or you can reuse what others have already done, have a look at https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js

Comment: I saw rdfstore-js but it hasn't had any commits for over 8 months and the documentation is really hard to understand. Do you know if it is in active development? Do you know about any tutorials on how to use it?

Comment: I don't know if it's being developed. Why not ask the author? It looks like an impressive piece of work that would take a lot of effort to reproduce. I think this is nearly as good as it gets around SemWeb.

Comment: rdfstore-js is not under active development (according to the creator) due to time constraints. It has been used in production environments but it was not built for it.

Comment: https://github.com/zazukoians/rdf-ext is an actively mantained implementation of rdf-interfaces.